# angular 15 navigating error - NG04013: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Tags: angular

i'm new to angular and i would like some help with navigating error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04013: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: NG04013: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.mjs:2630:19)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3060:40)
    at router.mjs:3009:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (router.mjs:3008:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (router.mjs:2922:14)
    at router.mjs:2907:10
    at map.js:7:37
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1168:17)
    at zone.js:1281:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at core.mjs:23864:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23864:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24165:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

my route module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [], },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the navigate command from LoginComponent:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  submit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'" color="primary">
  <mat-icon>local_fire_department</mat-icon>
  <span>Kanban Fire</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^15.2.0",
```

when i try to navigate from the app component it work just fine.
originally i tried to navigate from an injectable service, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're experiencing is related to the Router Outlet in Angular, which is a directive that acts as a placeholder for the router to insert components as you navigate through your application. The error message "Cannot activate an already activated outlet" suggests that there is an issue with the router outlet being activated multiple times.

To fix this issue, you can try the following:

1. Add a `*ngIf` directive to the `<router-outlet>` to ensure that it's not being rendered while navigating to the login page. Update your `app.component.html` as follows:

```html
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'" color="primary">
  <mat-icon>local_fire_department</mat-icon>
  <span>Kanban Fire</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet *ngIf="router.url !== '/login'"></router-outlet>
```

This will ensure that the router outlet is not rendered when the user is on the login page, which should prevent the error from being thrown.

2. You can also try using the `navigateByUrl` method instead of the `navigate` method in your `LoginComponent`. Update your `submit()` method as follows:

```js
submit() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}
```

This method directly navigates to the provided URL, which might help to prevent the error.

Hope It helps

Comment: the router-outlet is for both login and home components. with the ngIf addition i can't show the login component. 
i have already tried the navigateByUrl method

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).